# How can I resolve Windows 7 denying access to files?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Sometimes (randomly) I can't access files on Windows 7 because of permission errors. I'm system administrator with all rights given.

For example:

- I cannot open the `.exe` I just compiled
- I cannot modify any files in a folder
- An installer cannot rename a file
- Sometimes I cannot FTP upload files because of permission denied errors.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because windows treats the program which opened a file as this file's ultimate possessor and will prevent other programs from accessing that file. Your possible courses of action are:
 1. identify the program holding the file and close it (or close the file in it, which helps most times but not always)
 2. install something like [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) or [iobit unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/iobit-unlocker.php) (I have only tried the former and can attest that it works most of the time).